# Images and media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, image-scaling

I'm new with responsive design and am designing a web page starting with 240px width for old phones and building up from there.

On my banner image, which is a PNG, is it best to:
1) Start with my largest image and shrink it for each media query?
or
2) Start with a small banner and then display a higher resolution file for each breakpoint?

Stretching and shrinking images seems fine for vector graphics but on some gifs and other images it looks rather ugly.

So I wasn't sure if I should load one banner image that I manipulate or if I should have at least 3 images (phone, tablet, desktop sized) that I load at certain resolution trigger points.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say play around with it, see what works for you. Maybe make say a large, medium and small and input them in your media queries and see how they react, and go with what best works for your design. Most of the time I go with a large image and shrink it using html and media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, I'd say to use media-queries to find the size of the screen and use whatever image fits best.

Example of CSS:

```
.banner{
    background: url('banner-1024.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

@media all (max-width: 400px){
  .banner{
    background-image: url('banner-400.png');
  }
}

@media all (max-width: 900px){
  .banner{
    background-image: url('banner-900.png');
  }
}
```

But if you aren't expecting a lot of viewers on mobile devices, don't have the time to create the re-sized images, or just want the least amount of CSS, I've never had to much of a problem just using a large image for all devices.

If that's the case then just use the top four lines of code and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Azzie, thanks for this. This is what I had in mind. I wasn't sure if it was the best practice for resizing images as the browser window moves, though.

My main header is a raster image. I notice when I try to stretch it by increasing the window size that it looks kind of bad, but then the rest of the text is fluid and looks nice when the window resizes.

I've seen other responsive designs that are less fluid. They look kind of stiff until you hit the breakpoint then everything jumps into place.

It seems simpler to export multiple IMG from PS.

Comment: In short, the raster image doesn't seem to flow very well between sizes when the viewport is resized by dragging the edges. It becomes pixelated at high resolutions or too congested looking at small resolutions.

Comment: I've done responsive design for a while, and I used to worry about how it looked when it was being re-sized also.  But think about this, almost nobody who visits your page is going to re-size it after it loads.

Comment: That is a very good point. I guess I wanted it to look nice when people want to drag the window around, say to half size, so they can leave it open while they multi task on something else. Then again, I doubt that will be done on phones, especially on my site, which will be very text heavy and probably best suited to desktops.

Comment: Azzie Rogers, what about the new HTML <picture> tag?

Comment: @Inflames626 - nice element, but last I checked it lacks the support needed to be useful in public projects.

Answer (score 0):

using at least a few images works great for me, phones (iOS, Android, Opera Mini) seems to choose whitch one to download, without requesting those for desktop, and medium-screen-devices. I started with one desktop image, performance was horrible. Then tried few smaller for each media query (with a little bit worse quality at 240px ;) ). It's way much faster.